# Optimization in Banach space: Find functions that minimize the supremum of a convex operator.

Tags: optimization, banach-spaces, calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be compact. Denote by $C(D, \mathbb{R}^n)$ the space of continuous functions from $D$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $K$ be a real, symmetric, positive-definite $n \times n$ matrix and let $k \in C(D, \mathbb{R}^n)$.

We consider the following convex "functional":
$$\mathcal{F}:C(D, \mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow C(D
)$$
$$\mathcal{F}[b](x) := b(x)^T K b(x) - 2 k(x)^T b(x)$$
where $^T$ denotes transpose.

We are interested in the quantity
$$M_b := \sup_{x \in D} \mathcal{F}[b](x)$$

We are looking for the function $b \in C(D, \mathbb{R}^n)$ that minimizes this quantity, under the constraint that $b(x)$ lies on the probability simplex $\Delta$ for all $x$.
$$\inf_{\substack{b \in C(D, \mathbb{R}^n)} \\ b \in \Delta} ~ ~ \Big(\sup_{x \in D} \mathcal{F}[b](x)\Big)$$

Formally, the constraint $b \in \Delta$  is:
$$\forall x \in D: \sum_{i = 1}^n b_i(x) = 1 \text{ and } b_i(x) \geq 0 \text{ for i=1, ...,n} $$
Where, for $b \in C(D, \mathbb{R}^n)$, we write: $b(x) =  \begin{pmatrix}
    d_1(x)\\
    \vdots\\
    d_n(x)
  \end{pmatrix}$

I am looking for any reference that could help me solve this problem.
More precisely, references to any article / book related to the subject would already help. I don't even know that the name of this field of mathematics is.

Remarks:

- I am interested in numerical or analytical solutions to the above problem.
- An approximate solution would also be OK.
- I know the solution to the unconstrained version of the problem.
- The current setting is to look for solutions in the class of continuous functions, but that setting can be relaxed: in the end, piecewise continous is enough.